# Spinor and vector representation matrices commutation relation

Tags: angular-momentum, representation-theory, lorentz-symmetry, spinors, dirac-matrices

To show Lorentz invariance of Dirac equation P&S section 3.2 swap $\Lambda$ and $S(\Lambda)$ as both matrices commute. But why is it true? For example taking 
$${\cal J}^{01}=\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ \end{matrix}\right)\,,$$ and $$S^{03}=\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\  0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ \end{matrix}\right)\,,$$ $ [{\cal J}^{01},S^{03}]\neq0 $. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

$({\cal J}^{\mu\nu})^{\rho}{}_{\sigma}$ acts in a 4-vector representation of the Lorentz group while $(S^{\mu\nu})^a{}_b$ acts in the Dirac spinor representation, i.e. they don't live in the same representation despite both happen to be given by $4\times4$ matrices.

Comment: I understand that logically, but when I have an expression in matrix representations of both, I have just two matrices that obviously do not commute. What's the mathematical excuse for swapping them?

Comment: They live in different spaces.

Comment: @v_tal Qmechanic means to say that they act on different Hilbert spaces. For example, you can swap momentum operator of particle 1 with that of particle 2 for a composite system, because they live in different spaces. Am I correct, @Qmechanic?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.